# Difference between generic types notation in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

Is there any difference between those two notations?
[image]

and:

[image]

In the second case, I cannot access the fields of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you already noticed, they're different things. In the second example `In` is not bound to any type, so it is the same as `<In: Any?, Out: Temperature>`. This is why you can't access `value` property - `In` is just `Any?`.